# Facebook phonegap permissions pop not only on app start

Tags: javascript, facebook, cordova, cordova-plugins

I managed to get the Facebook plugin running on my Cordova Phonegap project however it does only work when it's on index.js file such as:

```
bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);

        document.addEventListener('deviceready', initApp, false);

        var fbLoginSuccess = function (userData)
        {
            getUserInfo();
        }

        function initApp()
        {
            facebookConnectPlugin.login(["public_profile"],
                fbLoginSuccess,
                function (error) { alert("" + error) }
            );
        }

        function getUserInfo(){

            facebookConnectPlugin.api('/me', null,
                function(response) {
                    alert('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
                });
        }        
    },
```

I want this to run when the user clicks the Facebook login button and not on the start of the App, however if I place a function call inside the .html file ou main.js I have an undefined function; this only works inside bindEvents and nowhere else... any help is appreciated thks.

Comment: Is your function from main.js in `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: Thks for the tip, but it's.

Comment: You didn't understood me. It was a question. Put your function outside `$(document).ready()` and it should work like in index.js.

Comment: I did, it calls the function but the plugin functions do not work.

Comment: Placed the function inside main.js but outside Jquery's document ready, works fine now! thanks for the help.

Comment: That's what I was saying. Glad you solved it.